# Is it possible to write python code inside Flutter using Android Studio?

Tags: python, android, api, flutter, backend

I'm working on Flutter project in Android Studio platform and I faced a problem with how to write and run python API code inside my Flutter project without letting it as a backend code in another platform? since when I run my Flutter project that connected with python API code in another platform as a backend using post method, it's worked with the emulator but it does not work with my physical android device.
So is there any recommend solution for either the first problem or the second.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to write python code Inside Flutter code
But you can write your api in different framework like Django ,mongodb and use it in your Flutter app

Comment: Do you mean that we cannot write python code inside Flutter code or inside Flutter project in general?

Comment: I mean we can't write python code inside Flutter code

Comment: Okay, do you know how to write inside Flutter project in Android Studio?

Comment: Also do you know how to connect my physical android device with my python API code? I already connect my Flutter project in Android Studio with my python code in visual studio code using post method and it worked with my emulator but it does not connect with a physical device.

Comment: For work with physical device you have to on developer mode in your device. Go to settings in your app and click 6-7 times on build number and then developer mode will be on

Comment: It is already on, is there any other solution to solve the connection problem between my real android device and python backend code using http post method?